# how to start two threads at the same time(or at the close time)

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class `Note` and a class `Meeting`. There is an `ArrayList` named `noteList` in class `Note`. When an object of `Meeting` is created it is then registered in the `noteList`.

I just want to demostrate in the main class that two objects of `Meeting` can be created at the same time (or at the close time). My program is:

```
public class Note{
    //some field and method hier
    public void add(Meeting m){
        notes.add(m);
    }
    private  static final List<Entry> notes =
        Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Entry>());
}

public class Meeting implements Runnable{
    public Meeting(Note note_1,Note note_2,Calendar calendar){
        note_1.add(this);
        note_2.add(this);}
        //some method
    }

    public class Test implements Runnable{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Note note_1 = new Note();                
            Note note_2 = new Note();
            Meeting m_1 = new Meeting(note_1,note_2);
            Meeting m_2 = new Meeting(note_2,note_1)
            Thread t1 = new Thread(m_1);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(m_2)
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }
        //t1,t2 are two thread and they start one to one(not at the same time).
```

I have read anywhere that `wait()`, `notify()` or `notifyAll()` can be used, but they must be used in a synchronized method. I have no synchronized methods in my program.

Comment: In your code as written, `m_1` is always created (instantiated) before `m_2` though they will both exist simultaneously in memory until the GC decides to clean them up. Do you mean something else? In any case if you search for why double checked locking for singletons doesn't work you'll get a very good overview of synchronisation issues in Java.

Comment: I think there is a missing.I mean how can m_1 and m_2 be created(instantiated) at the same time(or at the close time)

Comment: You are using synchronized methods because synchronizedList() return a list which has all its method synchronized.

Comment: The reason why i use synchronizedList to ArrayList notes is that in class Note i want to output the element in notes every 5 minutes.I have a run() in class Note.  i cannot paste the run() hier ,i shall add it to the question.

Comment: @echo Welcome to the community. I looked at the edit log on the question and I noted that you added a whole second question to the original post. If you have two questions (or arrive at a second follow up question) that are distinct in nature, you should strongly consider posting them as two questions.

Comment: Dear Tim Bender, I am a beginner to stackover. Because the second question is releated to the first. I shall change it . Sorry!

Answer (score 15):

This is as close as you are going to get to starting the two threads.

What you could do to synchronize the run methods even more is to have them wait on a [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) on the top of their run methods.

What this does is taking away the overhead of creating and starting Threads (the part that happens before your run method gets executed), and maybe also some freak scheduling oddities. You have no guarantee however, how concurrent the code after the latch will actually be executed.

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

Runnable r1 = new Meeting(latch);
Runnable r2 = new Meeting(latch);


// in Meeting

private final CountDownLatch latch;

public void run(){

   latch.countDown();
   latch.await();

   // other code
}
```

Comment: You can only guarentee that one thread does not pass await until the second one has reach countDown.  This ensures they are both start but one could stop running immediately after.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Yes, that is what I meant by "you have no guarantee however, how concurrent the code after the latch will actually be executed". All you can enforce is a strict ordering, if you want that.

Comment: +1 for showing a method which (with numerous repetition) could very likely cause concurrent execution. Note that a `CyclicBarrier` would also work in this case.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, there is no way to start two threads **at the same time**.

Let me explain better: first of all, the sequence `t1.Start();` and `t2.Start();` is executed with t1 first and, after that, t2. It means **only** that thread t1 is scheduled *before* thread 2, not actually started. The two methods take fractions of second each one, so the fact that they are in sequence cannot be seen by a human observer.

More, Java threads are **scheduled**, ie. assigned to be **eventually** executed. Even if you have a multi-core CPU, you are not sure that 1) the threads run in parallel (other system processes may interfere) and 2) the threads both start just after the `Start()` method is called.

Comment: You cannot start two threads at the same time, but you can synchronize in the run method. Of course, all you said about eventual execution still applies. But at least you can coordinate the sequence in which the run methods are executed, in case there is some inter-dependence.

Comment: When you are dealing with threads and/or multiple CPUs there is really no such thing as 'at the same time'. You need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

They are starting at "close" to the same time.  The point is that your code isn't blocking at `t1.start()`.

You might be able to see this by adding a print statement at the top of the `run()` method of the `Meeting` class, and another print statement right after `t2.start()`.  Something like this:

```
public class Meeting implements Runnable {
    private String name;
    public Meeting(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(name + " is running");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Meeting m_1 = new Meeting("meeting 1");
        Meeting m_2 = new Meeting("meeting 2")
        Thread t1 = new Thread(m_1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(m_2)
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        System.out.println("this might print first!");
    }
}

// possible output:
> this might print first!
> meeting 1 is running
> meeting 2 is running
```