# How to invoke two threads at same time?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to write Thread Interference Example.

Below is my code:

```
class Counter {
    private int c = 0;

    public void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public int value() {
        return c;
    }    
}
```

Suppose Thread A invokes increment at about the same time Thread B invokes decrement.
How to implement this one.

Comment: it is out of your hand, it depends on thread scheduler that which will get chance first, although there are concurrency control mechanism to serialize.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676244/how-to-start-two-threads-at-the-same-timeor-at-the-close-time

Comment: What about two thread, which are waiting for some event (for ex. time schedule)?

Comment: Run two threads several times, until you'll have an interference.. Pray, it might help.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Why not loop within these threads? Saves the thread creation and startup time.

Comment: why do you need increment and decrement at the same time ?

Comment: do you really need how to invoke two threads or you want to synchronize `increement` `decreement` function

Comment: @dbw invoke two threads at the same time. Thank you very much

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar I want to know the Interference problem

Comment: @still_learning How to do that one with loop. Thank you very much

Comment: In your `Thread` class: `public void run() { while(true) myCounter.increment(); }`. Then just start two of these threads which will then continously access `Counter.c`.

Comment: [thread concurrency control mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control)

Answer (score 2):

There is not guarantee how they will run it depends on OS scheduler. There is nothing better than this

```
Thread a = new ThreadA();
Thread b = new ThreadB();
a.start();
b.start();
```

Comment: What about two threads, which are waiting for some event (some precise  time event) and then simultaneously do some action?

Comment: This one will call one after another. Thank you very much

Comment: @Andremoniy when they wake up again depends on OS, no gurantees, assume there is one core, how can it run 2 thread similtuneously?

Comment: @codegeek *`This one will call one after another`* -- Again not sure, If suppose your CPU is capable to run more than one threads at a time (that is true for new CPUs) then it is possible that for some executing-instance in several try both executes same time.

Comment: @codegeek a.start();b.start(); does not guarantee that a will run first

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Then How can I get Thread Interference bug? What I will do get this one?

Comment: Do synchronization, locks, or AtomicInteger

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Sure, I'm talking about multicore system.

Comment: @Andremoniy makes no difference. 2 cores. 1 busy with another process. 2 threads are waiting. got signal. 1 core is free OS decides to run A, B is still waiting. no guarantee

Comment: There is no *guarantee*, no, but one can most definitely do 'better' than that at having them start executing as close together as possible.

Comment: +1 there are **no** guarantees with thread scheduling. The best you can do is the simplest thing, which is exactly this. Although I would add some code to the main thread to sleep it so it doesn't contend for scheduling with the two child threads - giving them a better chance at equal priority (maybe!)

Answer (score 1):

To get two threads to start executing at the same time you can use a latch.  (Which is to say, two threads that become *available* for execution as close together as possible.)  Still for a single increment/decrement each it will probably take many runs to observe an interference.  For a repeatable experiment you probably want to call increment/decrement several times in parallel and observe the final value of c.

```
final Counter counter = new Counter()
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
  latch.await();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    counter.increment();
  }
}}).start():
Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
  latch.await();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    counter.decrement();
  }
}}).start():
Thread.sleep(10);//give thread 2 a timeslice to hit the await
latch.countDown();
System.out.println(counter.value()); //non-zero value indicates interference
```

Comment: Will a latch be much better than calling start on both? I don't think so. It just moves the synch point somewhere from outside the thread to inside. Maybe it's a little better but the first thread to call the latch could be immediately swapped out, then you're no better off. With threads there are just no timing guarantees.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I provided a similar answer, but with random invocations. I would appreciate if you validate it.

Comment: @Bohemian yes it makes a difference, the # of iterations required to reliably see interference is much lower if you use the latch.  "There is no *guarantee*" vs "it generally works in practice on un-loaded machines" are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Now in this example if you try to execute and the output `false` shows *interference*.

### How it works:

Both the `Runnable`s keep a ***thread local count*** which is incremented for each invocation of `increment()` and `decrement()`. So after execution for some amount of time if we try to validate the values

Then you can say that:

`value of Counter = invocation of increment() - invocation of decrement()`.

But when you try to verify this at the end of execution you get `false`. Which shows that the actual counter value was not as expected.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
        Counter c = new Counter();
        IncrementingRunnable incRunnable = new IncrementingRunnable(c);
        DecrementingRunnable decRunnable = new DecrementingRunnable(c);

        Thread tA = new Thread(incRunnable);
        Thread tB = new Thread(decRunnable);

        tA.start();tB.start();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        stop = true;

        tA.join();
        tB.join();

        //verify value
        int actualCount = c.c;
        int expectedCount = incRunnable.count - decRunnable.count;
        System.out.println(actualCount == expectedCount);
}


 public static volatile boolean stop = false;

static class IncrementingRunnable implements Runnable{
      volatile int count = 0;
      private Counter counter;

      public IncrementingRunnable(Counter c) {
        this.counter = c;
      }
      @Override
      public void run() {
            while(!stop){
                counter.increment();
                count++;
            }
      }
}

static class DecrementingRunnable implements Runnable{
      volatile int count = 0;
      private Counter counter;

      public DecrementingRunnable(Counter c) {
        this.counter = c;
      }
      @Override
      public void run() {
          while(!stop){
            counter.decrement();
            count++;
        }
      }
}
```

Now try changing the primitive `c` in `Counter` to `AtomicInteger` and see the output again. You will find that now the output is `true`.

Comment: I have provided the explanation as to how this works.

Comment: @Bohemian I would greatly appreciate if you validate my answer.